# Get div id largest number in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How to get only the number with the largest value in the array?

I tried in the following example but I don't get the largest value ..., is this the best way?

```
<div id="1" class="number">Element 1</div>
<div id="3" class="number">Element 3</div>
<div id="5" class="number">Element 5</div>
<div id="9" class="number">Element 9</div>
<div id="6" class="number">Element 6</div>
<div id="4" class="number">Element 4</div>
```

```
     [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.number')).forEach(function(el) {
     var num = el.id;
     var largestnumber = (Math.max(num));
     alert("The largest number is"+largestnumber);
     });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
  
var data = [];  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.number')).forEach(function(el) {
     var num = parseInt(el.id);
     data.push(num);
     });
     
var largestnumber = Math.max(...data);
console.log(largestnumber);
```

```html
<div id="1" class="number">Element 1</div>
<div id="3" class="number">Element 3</div>
<div id="5" class="number">Element 5</div>
<div id="9" class="number">Element 9</div>
<div id="6" class="number">Element 6</div>
<div id="4" class="number">Element 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.max` accepts an array of integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). So you want something more like:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const max = Math.max(els.map(m => parseInt(m.id)));
```

`els.map(m => parseInt(m.id))` turns your array of objects into an array of integers. See [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var arr = [];
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.number')).forEach(function(el) {
     arr.push(Number(el.id))
     });
console.log(Math.max(...arr))
```